# jScrollPane Tabs - How to make them fadein/fadeout?

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I managed to get the [Vertical jScrollPane with tabs](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/invisibles.html) working. How can I make it fadein/fadeout? I've tried adding a delay and a fadein/fade out to `show()` and to `hide()` but it either doesn't work or it shows tabs where there should be.

Here's the code I've tried to modify. Everything is identical with the code on the jscrollpane site.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode"> 
        $(function()
        {
            // Create the "tabs"
            $('.tabs').each(
                function()
                {
                    var currentTab, ul = $(this);
                    $(this).find('a').each(
                        function(i)
                        {
                            var a = $(this).bind(
                                'click',
                                function()
                                {
                                    if (currentTab) {
                                        ul.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
                                        $(currentTab).hide();
                                    }
                                    currentTab = $(this).addClass('active')
                                                    .attr('href');
                                    $(currentTab).show().jScrollPane();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            );
                            $(a.attr('href')).hide();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this? What do you want to fade? The scroll pane or the tabs box?

```
var a = $(this).bind('click',function(){
if (currentTab) {
    ul.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(currentTab).fadeOut("slow");
}
currentTab = $(this).addClass('active').attr('href');
$(currentTab).fadeIn("slow").jScrollPane();
return false;
});
```

If you want to animate the scrollbar... :)

```
var a = $(this).bind('click',function(){
if (currentTab) {
    ul.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(currentTab).fadeOut("slow");
}
currentTab = $(this).addClass('active').attr('href');
$(currentTab).fadeIn("slow").jScrollPane();
$(".jspVerticalBar").css("opacity", "0");
$(".jspVerticalBar").animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I want the pane's to fade when switching from one to the other.

Comment: I've just tried it out and it works great! I've changed `$(currentTab).fadeOut("slow");` to the original `$(currentTab).hide();`because when switching panes, the previous pane temporarily appears while it fades out. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Thanks for the animation of the scrollbar! :D